# Reducibility of $x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I want to prove or disprove the statement:

> $x^2+1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ $\iff$ there exists $a$ such that $a^2=-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

How can I prove or disprove the proposition?

Comment: I am not sure why you are focusing on those two results. It is clear that the polynomial in question is not a unit, as the highest degree coefficient is $1$.

Comment: That is just examples of my failure. I wanted reduce circumstance to $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, but I coudn't have any progress. You don't have to mind the two theorems.

Comment: Can you show one of the directions? For example that if there is some $a$ with $a^2 = -1$ then the polynomial is reducible?

Comment: if part is clear. if a^2=-1 then x^2+1=(x-a)(x+a).

Comment: Ok, so to do the other direction, you will need to show that if the polynomial is reducible then it has a root (this is because it is quadratic and has invertible highest degree coefficient).

Comment: Yes. But the reason you just stated is somewhat strange to me. We need to show that 'if the polynomial is reducible then it has a root' but it's reason is irrelevant that 'it is quadratic and has invertible highest degree coefficient'.

Comment: No, both of those are important here. A polynomial of degree $4$ of higher can be reducible without having a root. And a polynomial with non-invertible highest degree term can split into factors where one is of degree $0$ without being a unit.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstand your comment. Then you said that 'if f(x) is quadratic and has invertible highest degree coefficient in $Z_n[x]$, then f(x) has root in $Z_n$. right?

Comment: Assuming it is also reducible, yes.

Comment: but how can I prove it? (and I am curious about the example of degree 4 you stated...) Can you attach related link?

Comment: For degree $4$, just take the product of two irreducible quadratics. For the proof, the hints by Andre in the answer are good.

Answer (score 6):

**Counterexample:**  Take $n=3\cdot 7=21$.  We have $$x^2+1=\left(7x^2+1\right)\left(15x^2+1\right)$$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z})[x]$, but neither $7x^2+1$ nor $15x^2+1$ is a unit of this polynomial ring.  Note that $a^2+1=0$ has no solution $a\in\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z}$ as such a solution would imply that $a^2+1=0$ holds in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as well as in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, which is absurd.

**However**, maybe the statement "$x^2+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $a^2+1=0$ has a solution $a\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$" is true if we add the assumption (which should be a necessary and sufficient condition for the quoted statement to hold) that $n$ is a prime power.  I will post a proof if I can show that my claim is true.

---

**Generalization:** Per request by lhf, I shall prove that $x^2+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ if $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_r^{k_r}$, where the integer $r$ is at least $2$, the $p_i$'s are pairwise distinct prime natural numbers, and the $k_i$'s are positive integers.  In fact, you can similarly show that every non-unit polynomial $p(x)$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[x]$ which is not a unit element in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{k_i}\right)[x]$ for at least two values of $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,r\}$ is reducible.  For example, if $n=6$, then $$x+2=(3x+4)(4x+5)$$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})[x]$.  Even more generally, let $S$ be a set of variables (it may be empty, finite, or infinite).  We can define the polynomial rings $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[S]$ with variables in $S$ (where $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[\emptyset]$ is the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ itself).  Then, every non-unit polynomial in $(
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[S]$ which is not a unit element in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{k_i}\right)[S]$ for at least two values of $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,r\}$ is reducible.  For instance, $$x^2+2y+3=\left(5x^2+10y+11\right)\left(16x^2+12y+13\right)$$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z})[x,y]$.

Consider $\mathbf{v}=\left(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_r\right)\in\{0,1\}^r$.  Define $a_\mathbf{v}$ and $b_\mathbf{v}$ to be the (unique) elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $a_\mathbf{v}\equiv v_i\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ and $b_\mathbf{v}\equiv 1-v_i\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,r$.  Define $$f_\mathbf{v}(x):=a_\mathbf{v}\,x^2+1\text{ and }g_\mathbf{v}(x):=b_\mathbf{v}\,x^2+1\,.$$  Then, $x^2+1=f_\mathbf{v}(x)\,g_\mathbf{v}(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  Hence, there are at least $2^{r-1}-1\geq 1$ essentially different nontrivial factorizations of $x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

**Proof of Reducibility over $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[S]$:**  For constant polynomials, the claim is easy to verify (also, see the remark below).  Let $p(S)\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[S]$ be a non-constant polynomial satisfying the condition.  Write $M(S)$ for the set of all monomials in variables in $S$ (note that $1\in M(S)$ always, even for $S=\emptyset$).  Then, $p(S)=\displaystyle\sum_{m\in M(S)}\,t_m\,m$ for some $t_m\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with $m\in M(S)$ (note that all but finitely many $t_m$'s are zero).  Let $\text{supp}\big(p(S)\big)$ denote the *support* of $p(S)$, i.e., the subset $T\supseteq \{1\}$ of $M(S)$ such that, for $m\in M(S)\setminus\{1\}$, $t_m\neq 0$ iff $m\in T$.  Observe that $\{1\}\subsetneq \text{supp}\big(p(S)\big)$.  Then, consider $$\mathbf{V}:=\left(\textbf{v}^i\right)_{i=1,2,\ldots,r}\in\left\{\textbf{a},\textbf{b}\right\}^r\,.$$
where $\textbf{a}=\left(a_m\right)_{m\in\text{supp}\big(p(S)\big)}$ satisfies $a_1=1$ and $a_m=0$ for all other $m$'s, whereas $\textbf{b}=\left(b_m\right)_{m\in\text{supp}\big(p(S)\big)}$ has $b_m=t_m$ for all $m$.  Take $f_\textbf{V}(S),g_\textbf{V}(S)\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[S]$ to be the polynomials $$f_\textbf{V}(S)=\displaystyle\sum_{m\in\text{supp}\big(p(S)\big)}\,\phi_m\,m\text{ and }g_\textbf{V}(S)=\displaystyle\sum_{m\in\text{supp}\big(p(S)\big)}\,\gamma_m\,m$$ where the $\phi_m$'s and the $\gamma_m$'s are the unique elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\phi_1\equiv v^i_1\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$, $\gamma_1\equiv 1+t_1-v^i_1\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$, $\phi_m\equiv v^i_m\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ and $\gamma_m\equiv t_m-v^i_m\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$, for all $i=1,2,\ldots,r$ and $m\in \text{supp}\big(p(S)\big)\setminus\{1\}$.  Here, $\textbf{v}^i=\left(v_m^i\right)_{m\in\text{supp}\big(p(S)\big)}$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,r$.  It follows that $p(S)=f_\textbf{V}(S)\,g_\textbf{V}(S)$, and so $p(S)$ has at least $2^{\rho-1}-1\geq 1$ essentially distinct nontrivial factorizations in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[S]$, where $\rho$ is the number of $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,r\}$ such that $p(S)$ is not a unit element in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{k_i}\mathbb{Z}\right)[S]$.

**Remark:** All irreducible constant polynomials are indeed known.  For example, $3$ is an irreducible element of $\mathbb{Z}/225\mathbb{Z}$.  In fact, we have the following statement for all positive integers $r$ ($r=1$ included): $u\,p_1^{\nu_1}p_2^{\nu_2}\cdots p_r^{\nu_r}$, where $u$ is a unit element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\nu_1,\nu_2,\ldots,\nu_r\in\mathbb{N}_0$, is an irreducible element of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[S]$ if and only if there exists exactly one $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,r\}$ such that $\nu_i\neq 0$ and this $i$ must satisfy $\nu_i=1<k_i$. (As you can see, $7$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}/189\mathbb{Z}$ because $7=14\cdot 14$ in $\mathbb{Z}/189\mathbb{Z}$ and $14$ is not a unit element.)

Comment: The interesting question is classifying the $n$ for which $x^2+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It can easily be seen that $x^2+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$ with at least two distinct prime factors.  That is why I raised the question about the relevance of $n$ being a prime power.

Comment: The proof is added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway how can I prove your general proposition that non unit polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z} [S]$ is reducible? It is hard to me. I struggle to take adequate v (tracing below argument), but fail.

Comment: I gave you a proof you had asked for.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have two questions. (1) When you explain support, you said "$m \in M(S), t_m \ne 0$ iff $m \in T$ or $m = 1$. I'm curious if it is typo. (2) You said "$p(S)$ has at least $2^{r-1}-1 \ge 1$ essentially distinct nontrivial factorization" but why not $2^r-2$?

Comment: (1) I changed the definition of support.  It should be clear now.  (2) You can pair up factorizations $p=fg$ with $p=gf$.

Comment: @Batominovski Thank you for answer. By the way, I think that I found a example that your method doesn't apply. Let $n=6$ and $f(x)=2x+1$ then $f(x)$ is not unit and not reducible in $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{6Z}$. I think you must add condition to $f(x)$ that there is at least two $i$ satisfying $f(x)$ is not unit in $p_i^{k_i}$.

Comment: Your counterexample is correct.  $2x+1$ is indeed irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.  So, your fix is probably a good fix.